# input onchange link autoclick in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm new to JavaScript. My question is how to link auto click `onchange` input

```
<input type="text" name="quantity"  id="quantity" class="form-control"  />
<input type="text" name="discount"  id="discount"  class="form-control"  />
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('cart_1').submit();" id="p" title="Edit Sale">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#quantity").change(function() {
   $('a').val(2).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `callback` function on `change` event in jquery.Like this.Enter value on both fields if you form fields are not empty form will be send.Try with one field blank field will not send.Hope it will help you.

```js
$("#quantity,#discount").on('change',function(){
var quantity=$("#quantity").val();
var discount=$("#discount").val();
if(quantity!=""&&discount!=""){
document.getElementById('anchor').click();
console.log('form send');
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity"  id="quantity" class="form-control"  />
<input type="text" name="discount"  id="discount"  class="form-control"  />
<a href="stackoverflow.com" id="anchor" title="Edit Sale">send</a>
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vn4toLu6/1/

Comment: what you want exaclty?explain please

Comment: `<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('<?php echo 'cart_'.$line ?>').submit();" id="p" title=<?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_update')?>  >`

Right now when I click on this link after editing quantity, it sends back request to server and gets the updated price.
But now what I want is that when user updates quantity field it automatically send request to server or call the above link.

Comment: @Asad Javed complete solution for you.Enjoy..also vote up answer.Thanks

Comment: <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('<?php echo 'cart_'.$line ?>').submit();" id="p" title=<?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_update')?> >    i am able to invoke or click on input change but when i try it with link <a> it doesn't work